# Get the list of candidates generated by ido

Tags: emacs, elisp, ido

Is it possible to get the list and save it in variable?
I run

```
(ido-completing-read "prompt: " '("one" "two" "three" "four" "five") nil nil "t")
```

and ido generates list of candidates `{two | three}`. I want something like this

```
(setq my-desired-list (ido-completing-read-silent '("one" "two" "three" "four" "five") nil nil "t"))
```

The value of `my-desired-list` after execution is `("two" "three")`.
I use complex settings for ido, it prepares very special filters for `choices` and I want to use the results directly.

Comment: Are we dealing with files, or frames, or  . . . ?

Comment: Function `ido-completing-read` gets arbitrary list in second argument.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `ido-matches' will contain the matched items from the last call to ido-completing-read. So this does what you want:

```
(defun ido-completing-read-silent (prompt choices initial-input)
  (ido-completing-read prompt choices nil nil initial-input)
  ido-matches)

(ido-completing-read-silent "prompt: " '("one" "two" "three" "four" "five") "t")
;; ("two" "three")
```

Comment: Can I make it realy "silent", e.g. without interaction with user?

Comment: Oh, I understand. You want to avoid having the user press the enter key. I'll have to think about that one.

Comment: Temporarily modify, or create a similar function, that alters the section of code `read-from-minibuffer` within `ido-read-internal` and/or alter or create a different type of `ido-make-prompt`?  I'm just spinning my wheels and thinking out loud.

Comment: @lawlist thanks for discussion, see my answer. I think it is useful and needs generalization.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun ido-completing-read-silent (prompt choices initial-input)
  (run-with-timer 0.0001 nil 'exit-minibuffer)
  (ido-completing-read prompt choices nil nil initial-input)
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (flx-propertize x nil)) ido-matches))

(equal (ido-completing-read-silent "prompt: " '("one" "two" "three" "four" "five") "t")
       '("three" "two"))
```

The solution can be used in another cases, for different interactive functions like `ido-completing-read`.